# Laravel Controller Function shows success but does not work

Tags: laravel, controller, routes

Hello i have a controller function called deactivate, if i click on a button it should do this function:

```
public function deactivate($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->verified = false;
        $user->save();
        return redirect('/adminmodul')->with('success', 'Nutzer wurde erfolgreich deaktiviert');
    }
```

and in my view the button looks so:

```
<td><a href="{{ route('adminmodul.deactivate',$user->id)}}" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-eye"></i></a></td>
```

and this is my route:

```
Route::patch('/adminmodul/{id}',[
    'as' => 'adminmodul.deactivate',
    'uses' => 'AdminController@deactivate'
]);
```

everytime i click on the button i get the success message but nothing happens and i dont know why

i can show you my complete controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use App\Angebot;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

    $angebote = DB::table('angebots')->first();
    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
    return view('adminmodul.index', compact('users', 'angebote'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    return view('adminmodul.create');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    return view('adminmodul.edit', compact('user'));
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name'=>'required',

    ]);
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->name = $request->get('name');
    $user->save();
    return redirect('/adminmodul')->with('success', 'Benutzer wurde geändert');
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $angebot = Angebot::where('firma', $id);
    $angebot->delete();
    $user->delete();

    return redirect('/adminmodul')->with('success', 'Nutzer wurde erfolgreich gelöscht');
}


public function deactivate($id)
{

    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->verified = false;
    $user->save();

   return redirect('/adminmodul')->with('success', 'Nutzer wurde erfolgreich deaktiviert');
}
}
```

and my routes:

```
Route::resource('/adminmodul', 'AdminController');
Route::get('/adminmodul/{id}', 'AdminController@deactivate')->name('adminmodul.deactivate');
```

i dont know what i do wrong?? because i do this the same way all the time

this is my table user:

[image]

Comment: what's the datatype of verified ?

Comment: the type is boolean

Comment: print $user after save data what you get

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: make sure your ```$user->id``` is not null.

Comment: put a dd($id) on your function and show us what you get

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
public function deactivate($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->verified = false;
    $user->save();
    return redirect('/adminmodul')->with('success', 'Nutzer wurde erfolgreich deaktiviert');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to save after assign the value,

```
public function deactivate($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->verified = false;
        $user->save();  // add this line 
        return redirect('/adminmodul')->with('success', 'Nutzer wurde erfolgreich deaktiviert');
    }
```

Update your routes like below,

```
Route::get('/adminmodul/{id}', 'AdminController@deactivate')->name('adminmodul.deactivate');

Route::resource('/adminmodul', 'AdminController');
```

Comment: Did you check your route actually hit your method ?

Comment: yes or? Route::patch('/adminmodul/{id}',[
    'as' => 'adminmodul.deactivate',
    'uses' => 'AdminController@deactivate'
]);

Comment: Why you use patch request instead of get request ?. Change route patch to get and see what happen.

Comment: still the same :/

Comment: If your routes hit your method then it should work. Make sure your routes hit the method by dd('hit') or something like this.

Comment: Can you upload your full routes ?

Comment: yes: Route::resource('/adminmodul', 'AdminController');

Route::get('/adminmodul/{id}', 'AdminController@deactivate')->name('adminmodul.deactivate');

Comment: i changed my post, maybe this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Check if the id is actually being received in the controller. Do a dd($id) to check if the controller function has received the id or not.

```
public function deactivate($id)
{
    dd($id)
    //rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your `id` is not null, use the `findOrFail()` method:

```
public function deactivate($id)
{
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->verified = false;
    $user->save();

   return redirect('/adminmodul')->with('success', 'Nutzer wurde erfolgreich deaktiviert');
}
```

Change your route to `put`:

```
Route::put('/adminmodul/{id}', 'AdminController@deactivate')->name('adminmodul.deactivate');
```

You should put this route **before** the `resource` route:

```
Route::put('/adminmodul/{id}', 'AdminController@deactivate')->name('adminmodul.deactivate');
Route::resource('/adminmodul', 'AdminController');
```

When your use the `resource` routes, laravel creates a route for this url `/adminmodul/{id}`. This may conflict with the route you created. Take a look [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers) for more info.

So, you should put the route you created before you declareted the `resource` route or you could change the url to avoid the conflict:

```
Route::put('/adminmodul/deactivate/{id}', 'AdminController@deactivate')->name('adminmodul.deactivate');
```